# Can a Python program with a file run on any computer?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm at the very start of my journey of Python learning.

We were given a .csv file for an assignment. I wrote the program, it's working fine but I have to send my program to my professor.

The beginning of my program is this :

```
from pathlib import Path
data_folder = Path("C:/Users/Fara/Desktop/Ex_Python_Fara_DL3ME")
file = data_folder / "mailing_list_data.csv"
file = open(file)
```

I have a feeling that when he's going to try to execute my program on Spyder, there's going to be an error. As you can see, the path of the .csv file is very specific. It's in Users, then Fara, then Desktop, etc... I think the 'mailing_list_data.csv' is going to be on a different path on my professor's computer. So I wanted to know how I could make my program run automatically on any computer without my professor having to change the path of the file manually. 
I've put the file in the same path as my Python script.

Thank you.

Comment: If you try to open "mailing_list_data.csv", it will search the current directory for the file. This is better than specifying an absolute file path. Alternatively, you can let your professor specify the path to the file via some kind of input.

Comment: Many possible ways to do it. You could make it a relative path, e.g. just `'mailing_list_data.csv'`, which is expected to be in the same folder as the script. Or you make it an *argument* which you can pass to the script when calling it. Or an environment variable. Depends on how you expect the script to get executed exactly and/or what your restrictions are.

Comment: @byxord Thank you so much ! It's working now ! :D